# Как проверить ключ на равенство со значением Dictionary, listbox C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Всем привет. Помогите пожалуйста с Dictionary

```
Dictionary<string, string> vocabulary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

Есть два listbox, в 1 listbox содержится ключ (string), во 2 listbox значение(string). 
Как с помощью  `listBox1.SelectedItem` проверить значение == ключа в listBox2?
Пример:

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string value = "";


        if (listBox1.SelectedItem(ключ) == listBox2.SelectedItem(значение))
        {

            MessageBox.Show("+");
        }         
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("-");
        }
    }
```

Comment: `if(vocabulary[/*тут ваш ключ*/] == /*тут ваше значение*/){  }`

Comment: @tym32167 спасибо большое, помогло.  if (vocabulary[listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()] == listBox2.SelectedItem.ToString())

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за помощь) Разобрался.

```
if (vocabulary[listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()] == listBox2.SelectedItem.ToString())
```